# Exclude home URL in htaccess authentication

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a website where I want to allow everyone to view http://localhost:8080/ but password protect all other URLs, for example, http://localhost:8080/home, http://localhost:8080/about, http://localhost:8080/blog-pretty-url, etc.

So far, this is my .htaccess code, but I could only password protect home and about pages, and exclude static files so that the homepage works fine.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI (\/(home|about-us)).*(?!(.*(css|js|png|svg|ico|jpg))) auth=1

AuthName "Please login"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/var/www/html/.htpasswd"

# first, allow everybody
Order Allow,Deny
Satisfy any
Allow from all
Require valid-user
# then, deny only if required
Deny from env=auth
```

I tried this regex too, but it's not working: `(\:\/\/).*(\/\w)(?!(.*(css|js|png|svg|ico|jpg)))`

Any help in writing a regex so that it protects all URLs except '/' and excludes static files from the blacklist would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

sadmansh,

You're on the right track but looking in the wrong direction. This is actually much more simple than it seems. All you need to do is password protect everything and then add a rule to allow all to visit a certain page which in your case is "http://localhost:8080/".

First, password protect every file/directory.

Afterwards, use the following to allow users to visit that particular link you want to give free access to.

Replace "index.html" with the file you would like to share.

```
<Files "/index.html">
  Allow from all
  Satisfy any
</Files>
```

Please let me know if this helps! Have a good one.